# Is there any difference between 'get away' and 'run away' in this context?

Tags: word-usage, difference

For these expressions

> The whole movie was about him **getting away** from cops.
>
> The whole movie was about him **running away** from cops.

Both **run away** and **get away** mean escape, but does **get away** fit in this context?

Comment: "Get away" does fit in that context and can mean getting away by any means necessary.

Comment: And just to be clear, *get way* is **not** idiomatic.

Comment: @StoneyB, unless you're talking about a "getaway car"! :-)

Comment: They're not exactly equivalents here. In #1, it's more or less a certainty the main character is still free at the end of the movie. In #2, it's quite possible the movie actually ends with him being caught or killed.

Comment: What @FumbleFingers said, You can *run* away but still not *get* away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both verbs make sense in your context, but they mean slightly different things.

**Getting away** implies success: like FumbleFingers said, the movie probably ends with the character still on the lam. It also implies, albeit to a lesser extent, that the cops initially had custody of the character, which he escaped.

**Running away** does not imply success. I don't know if I'd go so far as to say it implies *failure*, mind you, but I wouldn't be as hopeful about the eventual fate of a character who was *running* away as I would be about one who was *getting* away. **Running away** also does not imply escape: he could have started off in police custody, or he could have started off free as a bird, we don't know which.

In other contexts, these verbs may or may not be interchangeable. For example, teenagers *run away* from home to *get away* from an abusive parent, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [it's suitable](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+away) in this context.

> get away (from someone or something)
>
> 1. to escape from someone, something, or some place.

compare to [run away](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/run+away):

> run away (from someone or something)
>
> to flee someone or something

Answer (score 1):

To run away **specifies** how somebody or something got away, in this case, on foot.

To get away is **ambiguous**, you don't have to specify how somebody did it, and usually you use it if you don't know.

Here's an example:

```
The robbers got away before the police arrived
```

In the above example, the past tense of to get away is used. Because the speaker does not know **how** the robbers got away from the police, the speaker uses the verb to get away to let people know that he doesn't know **how** the robbers got away.

Comment: "Run away" can be used figuratively: it doesn't require being on foot.

Answer (score 0):

*get away* means do some thing bad and not be punished for it, and 
*run away* means go quickly away from a place.

Comment: "Do something bad and not be punished for it" is the definition of "get away **with**", ***not*** the definition of "get away".