# Escape, run away, get away, flee

Tags: word-usage

> I'm having a lot of issues with a sentence I need to write. I need to
>   say something like **"Run away from daily routine and escape to our
>   paradise resort."**

But, without saying "from daily routine and escape". In the context the reader already knows where the reader has to run away from.

The sentence I would like to write is:

> "Run away to our paradise resort."

But I'm not sure if this is correct in English. How can I put this idea into words in English?

Answer (score 2):

**run away** or [flee](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flee) sounds like something that refugees do: it's not something that you would want to associate with a paradise resort.

[escape](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/escape) is probably a good word to use about the daily routine. It suggests freedom, which is a positive idea. **get away** is similar.

There is a significant difference between get away and run away, as explained [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3855/is-there-any-difference-between-get-away-and-run-away-in-this-context?rq=1)

I would recommend using escape for the first clause, then something different,  also with positive connotations, in the second clause.

> **escape** from daily routine and visit/come to/find sanctuary in our paradise resort.

Comment: Hi @JavaLatte
What I would like to say is verb + "to our paradise resort". I don't want to say verb + "from daily routine" + "tou our paradise resort". Because the reader, already knows from where he/she has to escape.

Comment: Ok, so you just want the second clause but you want to imply the first? In that case, **find sanctuary in** might be worth considering.