# What is the difference between run away, get away, break away and go away?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

What is the difference between **run away**, **get away**, **break away**, and **go away**?

About get away and run away, somethings were explained [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/89433/escape-run-away-get-away-flee), but what about other phrases?

I searched and found it as a polemical topic. It would be creditable that on one page we discuss them as a reference. We have other words like **make off**, **abscond**, **flee**, **leave**, escape from, etc., as others put forward them as examples, so far.

Comment: Most of those have multiple meanings depending on context. Can you narrow down what you want to know and perhaps quote some dictionary definitions so people do not repeat your researches?

Comment: ***run away = flee*** - usually, but not always ***escaping***. But if you ***get away*** you definitely *did* escape. ***Breaking away*** is more often used figuratively to mean ***parting company*** with some larger group (leaving a political party, for example) - often with the implication that one will continue to do similar things - just not *within* that larger group. ***Going away*** is far more general, covering everything from an exasperated imperative ***Oh, go away**!* to ***I'm going away on holiday tomorrow***.

Answer (score 1):

*Run away* - Expectation is that you physically turn around and run with your legs away from X.  You should be scared.

- Sometimes used to mean *escape* if the person/thing escaping didn't have a specific destination in mind.
- The noun *runaway* can mean a child who left his family without them immediately knowing but also can mean other situations like a prisoner who has escaped, etc.

*Get away* - Expectation is that you separate yourself from X or increase your distance.   There might be a safety or privacy concerned.  Usually this is a strong, direct request but not necessarily mean.

- Also, if something is hunted and escapes, it can be said to have *got away*.
- The noun *getaway* typically means *vacation* the phrase *get away* can sometimes mean "to take a vacation."

*Break away* - This is used when the context is one or more people (or things) separating from a group to work on something themselves.  This tends to imply a temporary split.

- The noun *breakaway* has a couple meanings not directly related.

*Go away* - You are not welcome in the same vincinity as X.  You did something wrong if someone's telling you this and not specifiying a destination.

- You might say someone *went away* if they left and no one really cared that they left, or everyone wanted them to leave.